# Gradient fill rectangle using grid.rect in r

Tags: r, grid, gradient, fill

I am trying to create a colorbar using grid.rect on a grid plot in R. I would like the colorbar to have a gradient fill from red to yellow to blue in 100 steps going from left to right.

```
require(colorspace)
require("grid")
grid.rect(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.8, "npc"),
      width = unit(0.5, "npc"), height = unit(0.05, "npc"), 
      just = "centre",
      gp = gpar(col = NA, fill =colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "blue"), (100), "y"))
```

The rectangle I am getting is only one color, red, instead of a gradient of color.

Comment: Try with `x = unit(seq(0,0.5, length=100), "npc")`

Comment: consider grid.raster too

Comment: Thanks, @ user20650! Changing to x = unit(seq(0,0.5, length=100), "npc") worked!

Comment: @baptiste, I tried using grid.raster and was able to get the colors correctly, but the dimension of my box was off. I also tried using grid.lines to create a rectangle, but I couldn't get the spacing correct. I think I need to read more about the npc to use the grid.raster function. Thank you both for your help!